# textbox in continuous form populated from different table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a continuous form in an access 2010 database that outputs a separate row of data for each customer from a customers_table.  The continuous form is for data display only, and no data entry or editing is allowed.  One of the textboxes on the continuous form is populated with data that was entered using a combobox in a different form used for data entry.  In the textbox on the continuous form, enabled is set to no, and locked is set to yes, so that the textbox is not editable in the continuous form.  However, in the separate data entry form, ***the combobox entered the id for the selection the user chose, instead of entering the text.  Therefore, in the continuous form, only an id number is shown, when the user needs to see the text of the specific option which is encoded in that id number.***

I think I want to keep the id in the customers data table, in order to retain freedom to make subtle changes in the combobox options later.

**So how do I modify the textbox in the continuous form to populate with the textual value associated with the id number?** This would seem to involve some sort of SQL like:

```
"Select textValue FROM comboboxsource_table WHERE comboboxsource_table.ID=textbox.Text"
```

However, I have no idea where to put this in the Access GUI.  The Control Source field in the Data tab of the property sheet for the textbox does not seem to allow this sort of syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not editing the data, put a **query** behind the form instead of a **table**.  Then, just pull the field you need into the query and VOILA!  Problem solved.  :o)

Comment: Thank you.  This did it.  +1 for the quick response yesterday, and credit for the answer.